# Including stat_summary results in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, finance, legend-properties

[image: ***enter image description here***]

I have the following plot, but I would like to within the plot somewhere - preferably in the legend include descriptive statistics, such as mean, std.dev, kurtosis etc. ??

Comment: Or is this even possible ?

Comment: use geom_text() to add what you want!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using `annotate` and `capture.output`:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")
m <- loess(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)
out <- capture.output(print(summary(m)))
out2 <- paste0(out[-1], "", collapse = "\n")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() + 
  annotate("text", label = out2, x = 4, y = 5, size = 6, hjust = 0)
```

Please see the result below.

[image: Summary output]